# c++ function saving extra empty entries to a file

Tags: c++

i made this function to modify one specific field on existing entries in a binary file. It sure does its job, but also adds another full entry with every field in 0 to the file. any ideas about what could be causing this? before i added the "modOk == false" verification inside the while, the program would add several entries instead of one.

```
void option12(){
proyecto datos;
int id;
bool modOk=false;
system("cls");
cout << "Type project ID: ";
cin >> id;
FILE * p;
p = fopen("proyectos.tky","rb+");
if (p == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
while(fread(&datos, sizeof datos, 1, p) == true && modOk == false){
    if(id == datos.idPro && datos.estado == true){
        system("cls");
        cout << "Project found" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Type new value: ";
        cin >> datos.valor;
        long bytes;
        bytes = ftell(p) - sizeof datos;
        fseek(p, bytes, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&datos, sizeof datos, 1, p);
        system("cls");
        cout << "Data modified correctly" << endl;
        modOk = true;
    }
}
fclose(p);
if(modOk == false){
    system("cls");
    cout << "Project not found" << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

datos is a struct containing several variables:"idPro" contains an automatically assigned unique number. "estado" checks if the entry is active and "valor" is a value that is what im trying to modify.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of just a code snippet.

Comment: read/write operations should be separated by a file positioning operation (from the man page of fopen, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html ). Add an `fseek(p,0,SEEK_CUR);` after the fwrite line to enforce this. Also, you should compare the return value of fread to 1, not to true.

Comment: @FBergo you were right, It was all about the incorrect return value. if you want so, post this as an answer, so ill mark this as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read/write operations should be separated by a file positioning operation (from the [man page of fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) ).

Add an `fseek(p,0,SEEK_CUR);` after the fwrite line to enforce this.

Also, you should compare the return value of fread to 1, not to true.

Answer (score -1):

Consider that your struct (proyecto) is not byte aligned, and the compiler may be padding it.  If so, define the expected size of the struct and use that instead of sizeof(proyecto)

Comment: That's not it, sizeof will return the padded size. His read/write cursors are off because he's not doing an fseek between fwrite and fread.